# SQL Query to return Yes/No Based on a Subquery with Many-Many Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have a many-to-many relational schema with 3 tables: Users, Teams, and Teamuser.

Since a user can be on many teams and a team can have many users, teamuser is a table that joins users.id to teams.id.

I'd like to do a query that asks "With a given user ID, show me all of the teams in the teams table, with a calculated field called "member" that returns 1 if the given user is a member of that team, and a 0 otherwise"

Is there a way to do this with one query directly in MySQL?

TeamUser:

```
id  teamid  userid
5   1 [->]  1 [->]
1   1 [->]  2 [->]
2   2 [->]  2 [->]
6   3 [->]  1 [->]
```

teamid is a foreign key joined to Teams.id. userid is a foreign key on Users.id

Teams:

```
id  name
1   Whomping Willows
2   Chudley Cannons
```

Users:

```
id  username    
1   fred
2   finn    
3   paul    
16  pickles
```

Comment: show the table schema and how they are related.

Comment: Updated with the schema

Comment: why does your title mention many many joins and a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run something like the following to get the Cartesian product and then do the correlated sub-select wrapped in a coalesce to indicate membership?

select u.username,   t.teamname, 
COALESCE((select 1 from teamusers itu where itu.teamid = t.teamid and itu.userid = u.userid), 0)
from users u, teams t
where  u.username = 'finn'

Warning though this will not scale well as it does a select from team users for each row in the outer Cartesian product.  More teams == more rows to run the sub-select

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it

```
select
t.id,
t.name,
case when x.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end as `member`
from teams t
left join (
 select 
 tu.userid,
 tu.teamid
 from teamuser tu 
 left join users u on u.id = tu.userid  
 where u.id = 1 -- change the user id here which you are looking at
)x
on x.teamid = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to display result with two columns: first = **Team**, second - **Member**. Result set will consist with all of the teams, and member column - is given username is a member of the team. Then, you can use following query:

```
SELECT a.name AS team_name,
      CASE WHEN c.username = 'fred' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS member 
  FROM Teams AS a JOIN TeamUser AS b ON a.id = b.teamid
                  JOIN Users AS c ON b.userid = c.id;
```

Comment: This returns more than one row per team

Answer (score 0):

(Updated after actually testing on MySQL rather than Oracle.)

You could work along

```
set @userID = 1;

SELECT
  TeamsOuter.name
  , CASE IFNULL((SELECT Users.id FROM Users JOIN TeamUser ON Users.id = TeamUser.userID JOIN Teams ON TeamUser.teamID = Teams.id WHERE Teams.id = TeamsOuter.id AND Users.id = @userID), 0) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END member
  , IF((SELECT Users.id FROM Users JOIN TeamUser ON Users.id = TeamUser.userID JOIN Teams ON TeamUser.teamID = Teams.id WHERE Teams.id = TeamsOuter.id AND Users.id = @userID) IS NULL, 0, 1) memberToo
FROM Teams TeamsOuter
;
```

using either `CASE` or `IF`.
As the question is explicit on "With a given user ID […]", this is being used in the query.

NB: When checking the results: "TeamUser" does reference a team with "teamID" 3, which does not exist…

If you wanted actually everything in one place:

```
SELECT
  UsersOuter.userName
  , TeamsOuter.name
  , IF((SELECT Users.id FROM Users JOIN TeamUser ON Users.id = TeamUser.userID JOIN Teams ON TeamUser.teamID = Teams.id WHERE Teams.id = TeamsOuter.id AND Users.id = UsersOuter.id) IS NULL, 0, 1) member
FROM Teams TeamsOuter, Users UsersOuter
ORDER BY UsersOuter.userName, TeamsOuter.name
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3db40/2/5)